# Rename directory names recursively

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I would like to rename all directories (recursively) by changing all occurrences of spaces to underscores. E.g.

Before change:

```
product images/
  2010 products/
  2011 products/
  2012 products/
misc images/
nav images/
```

(etc.)

After change:

```
product_images/
  2010_products/
  2011_products/
  2012_products/
misc_images/
nav_images/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you have "product images" and "product_images" directories already in existence then what should happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [fixnames](https://github.com/pdkl95/fixnames/blob/master/README.md). You would do something like:

```
fixdirs -x \s -r _ *
```

Be sure to first test this out on a *different root directory*, one you're not worried about munging, before applying this to your real directory.

Comment: This application isn't installed on my machine nor is it in my Ubuntu repos. :\

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to setup and use from the Git repo, as near as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename` command:

```
rename -v 's/ /_/g' * */* */*/* */*/*/*
```

If you use Red Hat (or similar distributions as CentOS...), then the `rename` command is different:

```
rename -v ' ' _ * */* */*/* */*/*/*
```

This will also rename the spaces of the filenames, not only directories. But I guess it is what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl with File::Find module you can implement something like this:

```
use File::Find;

my $dirname = "../test/";

finddepth(sub {
  return if /^\.{1,2}$/; # ignore '.' and '..'
  return unless -d $File::Find::name; # check if file is directory
  if (s/\ /_/g) {        # replace spaces in filename with underscores
    my $new_name = $File::Find::dir.'/'.$_; # new filename with path
    if (rename($File::Find::name => $new_name)) {
      printf "Directory '%s' has been renamed to '%s'\n",
             $File::Find::name,
             $new_name;
    } else {
      printf "Can't rename directory '%s' to '%s'. Error[%d]: %s\n",
             $File::Find::name,
             $new_name,
             $!, $!;
    }
  }
}, $dirname);
```

Before:

```
% tree test 
test
├── test 1
├── test 2
└── test 3
    └── test 3 4
```

After:

```
% tree test 
test
├── test_1
├── test_2
└── test_3
    └── test_3_4
```

Answer (score 0):

I poked around a bit and found this script. Should do what you need to do very well.

http://david.lutolf.net/dt/ulb/fixnames

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one line:

```
mv "product images" product_images && for i in product_images/**; do mv "$i" "${i// /_}"; done
```

Comment: This will work on more than just directories, I think. What happens to files in the recursion, which have spaces in them?

Comment: Don't forget `shopt -s globstar` if you're going to use `**` as this is not set by default on Bash 4.x and as you probably know doesn't work an Bash 2.x or 3.x, at least not recursively

Comment: Interesting points @SiegeX however it worked for me without this shopt in bash 3.2.48. I have even tried disabling each & every shopt and it still worked fine.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: This command recursively picks only directories not files inside them.

Comment: I tested the `for` loop on my machine, and it listed both files and directories within the target folder.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Not sure why! I have many sub-directories and files in a dir called `test` on my system and `for i in test/**; do echo "$i"; done` only lists directories for me skipping all files. I have `bash 3.2.48` on `Mac OS 10.6.8`

Comment: I just tried it again, and it lists files as well as folders. I can even specify extensions in the `do` block (e.g. `$i.txt`) and get a listing of just those files. I have bash 3.2.48 on Mac OS 10.7.2.

Comment: @anubhava In bash 3.x there is no difference between `**` and `*` other than the fact that it is misleading since `**` has syntactical meaning in bash 4.x.  Your command in 2.x or 3.x isn't recursive, it will only traverse one level deep.